# Using gnuplot to generate a set of numbered images

Tags: python, variables, filenames, gnuplot

I'm a newbie in Python and I would like to ask you, how can I get images (a lot of images) made by Gnuplot.py with variable in name? I have this function, which creates single image:

```
def printimage(conf, i):
   filename = str(i) + "out.postscript"
   g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
   g.title('My Systems Plot')
   g.xlabel('Date')
   g.ylabel('Value')
   g('set term postscript')
   g('set out filename')
   databuff = Gnuplot.File(conf, using='1:2',with_='line', title="test")
   g.plot(databuff)
```

And this function is used in for loop:

```
i = 0
for row in data:
   config_soubor.write(str(i) + " " + row[22:])
   printimage("config_soubor.conf", i)
   i = i + 1
```

I still can't get rid of error "undefined variable: filename".

Thanks,
Majzlik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your python script is passing

```
set out filename
```

to gnuplot.  There 'filename' is part of the command string; the variable `filename` you set in your script is not being passed to gnuplot.  You could try replacing

```
g('set out filename')
```

with

```
g('set out "'+filename+'"')
```

Comment: Still the same error, undefined variable: out203... Could the fact, that python said "out203" instead of "out203.postscript", be the point of that problem? Is it possible, the name of that file is interpreted as another variable?
btw. I edited line with variable to:
    
    filename = "out" + str(i) + ".postscript"

Comment: My mistake, the filename needs to be in quotes.  See my edit.  Gnuplot will create a postscript file `out203` properly, but you may want to add the extension so other programs know it is a postscript file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the [`hardcopy`](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/doc/Gnuplot/_Gnuplot/Gnuplot.html#hardcopy) method?

#### Documentation

```
hardcopy (
        self,
        filename=None,
        terminal='postscript',
        **keyw,
        )
```

> Create a hardcopy of the current plot.
>
> Create a postscript hardcopy of the current plot to the default printer
>   (if configured) or to the specified filename.
>
> Note that gnuplot remembers the postscript suboptions across terminal
>   changes. Therefore if you set, for example, color=1 for one hardcopy
>   then the next hardcopy will also be color unless you explicitly choose
>   color=0. Alternately you can force all of the options to their defaults
>   by setting mode=default. I consider this to be a bug in gnuplot.

#### Example

See [example call](https://www.astro.rug.nl/~onderwys/PYTHON_DOCS/Gnuplot/Gnuplotdemo.html):

```
g.hardcopy('gp_test.ps', enhanced=1, color=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot expects a line of the form `set output "filename"`.  Notice that the filename *must be a string*.  So, for your example, it would be something like:

```
g('set out "%s"'%filename)
```

or using newer style string formatting:

```
g('set out "{0}"'.format(filename))
```

---

There are a few other things which could be done better.  In general:

```
i = 0
for x in whatever:
    ...
    i = i + 1
```

is better written as:

```
for i,x in enumerate(whatever):
    ...
```

Also, again using string formatting:

```
str(i) + " " + row[22:]
```

can be transformed to:

```
'%d %s'%(i,row[22:])
```

or:

```
'{0} {1}'.format(i,row[22:])
```

These are minor things and in this script it probably doesn't make a huge difference either way, but they'll be good to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad for every advice. :-)